# Disable compress the author year in natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using the natbib package, in the text I need the citation like

> (Oganov 2010a, Oganov 2010b, Oganov 2011)

but i am getting the output

> (Oganov 2010a,b,2011)

How to disable the compression in the `natbib` package

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

examples for systems that have been studied successfully
\citep{Oganov-2010c,Oganov-2010b,Oganov-2011}.


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Oganov, Ma, Lyakhov, Valle and Gatti}{Oganov {\em et~al.}}{2010{\em a}}]{Oganov-2010c}
Oganov, A.R., Ma, Y.~M., Lyakhov, A.~O., Valle, M., and Gatti, C. (2010{\em
  a}).
\newblock Evolutionary crystal structure prediction and novel high-pressure
  phases.
\newblock In {\em High-Pressure Crystallography: From Fundamental Phenomena to
  Technological Applications} (ed. E.~Boldyreva and P.~Dera), NATO Science for
  Peace and Security Series B: Physics and Biophysics, pp.\  293--323. Springer
  Netherlands.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Oganov}{Oganov}{2011}]{Oganov-2011b}
Oganov, A.~R. (ed.) (2011).
\newblock {\em Modern Methods of Crystal Structure Prediction}.
\newblock WILEY-VCH Verlag \& Co. KGaA.
\newblock ISBN: 978-3-527-40939-6.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Oganov, Lyakhov and Valle}{Oganov {\em
  et~al.}}{2011}]{Oganov-2011}
Oganov, A.~R., Lyakhov, A.~O., and Valle, M. (2011).
\newblock How evolutionary crystal structure prediction works -- and why.
\newblock {\em Acc. Chem. Res.\/},~\textbf{44}, 227--37.

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Oganov, Ma, Lyakhov, Valle and Gatti}{Oganov {\em et~al.}}{2010{\em b}}]{Oganov-2010b}
Oganov, A.~R., Ma, Y.~M., Lyakhov, A.~O., Valle, M., and Gatti, C. (2010{\em
  b}).
\newblock {Evolutionary crystal structure prediction as a method for the
  discovery of minerals and materials}.
\newblock {\em Rev. Min. Geochem.\/},~\textbf{71}, 271--298.

\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With author-year citation call-outs, adding the option

```
sort
```

when loading the `natbib` package will suppress compression of the year labels. In the case of your example code, the year labels will be shown as `2010a, 2011, 2010b` instead of as `2010a,b, 2011`.

Do note that with the `sort` option in force, the ordering of the citation call-outs generated by `\citep` will not necessarily be the same as the ordering of the keys in the argument of `\citep`. Instead, the ordering of the typeset citation call-outs will correspond to the ordering of the entries in the bibliography.

---

*Addendum*: If you wish to repeat the authors' names as well as provide separate year labels, you need to provide three separate `\citealp` statements:

```
(\citealp{Oganov-2010c}, \citealp{Oganov-2010b}, \citealp{Oganov-2011})
```

Compared with `\citep`, `\citealp` (i) omits the surrounding parentheses and (ii) omits the comma between the author(s)'s names and the years.

Comment: thanks for your timely help, I tried but i am getting the same output,

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran - Did you rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more*?

Comment: yes, l rerun the latex

Comment: I think some hacking need to be done in the natbib package, sort & compress option is working only on the numbered citation, but in the author year style compression is added as default.

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran - Without the `sort` option, I get `(Oganov et al, 2010a,b, 2011)`. In contrast, *with* the `sort` option, I get `(Oganov et al, 2010a, 2011, 2010b)`. Are you getting different outputs? If so, please state exactly what you're getting.

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran - Please note that I haven't been using the `sort&compress` option, but the `sort` option. Indeed, as the package's user guide states, the `sort&compress` is only meaningful if numeric-style citation callouts are to be generated.

Comment: thanks for your help, I need the Author name should be repeat.

Comment: I need the out put like (Oganov 2010a, Oganov 2010b, Oganov 2011)

Comment: @venkatesanRamachandiran - I just posted an addendum to my answer, in which I mention using the `\citealp` macro instead of `\citep`.