# Keep author name in multiple citations with common author

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I am using bibtex and natbib. The default style is to drop the name of the author when citing multiple works with a common author, e.g.:

[Author et al., 2001,2002,2003]

but I want it to read:

[Author et al., 2001; Author et al., 2002; Author et al., 2003]

```
% tex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
 Blah blah blah \citep{author01,author02,author03}.
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}

% bib file
@misc{author01,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2001},
title = {blah},
}
@misc{author02,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2002},
title = {blah},
}
@misc{author03,
author = {Author, A.},
year = {2003},
title = {blah},
}
```

Comment: I don't think `natbib` supports this out of the box. I think you have to cite them separately. See the *Addendum* to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/298618/87678